# OpenGL and switchable graphic cards

Tags: ati, opengl, hybrid-graphics

I use a laptop and this laptop has readon AMD Radeon HD 6470M and onboad graphic card.
When I run `fglrxinfo`, I get this error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  136 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
  Serial number of failed request:  12
  Current serial number in output stream:  12
```

Is it a problem ? Because of I reason I can't use opengl.
Because, I can't run any opengl applications.

Answer (score 0):

Install your display driver. http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx